# Accessing Powershell Arguments in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a simple c# console application that i am running through a Powershell ps1 file. I would like to take the argument passed in through $args[0] when the script is called, and use that in a method i have in my c# application. I have found a lot for the reverse, but nothing to helpful for what i am trying to do. Any input would be much appreciated. This is roughly what i have tried recently. Thank you!

```
$filePath = $args[0]
$Check = New-Object -ComObject "Take c# file and try to make into    object"
$Check.hasFile($filePath)
Start-Process -FilePath "Path to c# exe"
```

.hasFile is the c# method that i am trying to pass the Powershell argument to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want to pass your script variable as an argument into your C# application? If so, you can just make the `Main` method of your `Program.cs` accept an array of strings, and then pass your script variables to `Start-Process` when you launch the application:

```
$myargs = @($args[0],$myvariable, .... <whatever>)
Start-Process MyCSharpApplication.exe $myargs
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

To clarify, in the simple case that you just have one variable you want to pass in, you don't even need the separate array variable. You can just do:

```
Start-Process MyCSharpApplication.exe $myvariable
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want to do! So in your example, would <whatever> be what i would call the array in program.cs so the variable could be used in program.cs?

Comment: The normal convention is to use the following method signature: `static Main(string[] args)` (which is the method stub you should have had when you created the project, no?). So then if you're calling your C# application from your `.ps1` script with one argument, you would just access `args[0]` inside your `Main` method

Comment: I cannot tell you how long i've been trying to figure out that simple line of code. Thank you, I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: No problem at all, glad to have been of assistance!